# animated "blob" in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am currently playing around with a blob code and have a small problem.

The problem is that sometimes the blob gets inverted so the white color gets inside the blob itself and makes a white hole in it which I don't really want.

Any suggestions on how to fix this, so the blob stays all the time as one little nice piece?

This is the one im playing around with:
http://wonderfl.net/c/rYzh

```
class Blob extends Sprite
{

    private var speed    :Number = .01;
    private var grav     :Number = .25;
    private var dist     :Number = 27;
    private var k        :Number = .55;
    private var damp     :Number = .99;
    private var cx       :Number = 370;
    private var cy       :Number = 0;
    private var points   :Array  = [];
    private var mids     :Array  = [];
    private var numPoints:Number = 30;
    private var oneSlice :Number = Math.PI * 2 / numPoints;
    private var radius   :Number = 100;

    public function Blob()
    {
        for (var i:Number = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
        {
            var angle:Number = oneSlice * i;
            var obj:Object = {x:Math.cos(angle) * radius + cx, y:Math.sin(angle) * radius + cy, a:angle - Math.PI / 2, wave:i*.08, vx:0, vy:0};
            points[i] = obj;
        }

        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

    }

    private function update(event:Event):void
    {
        this.graphics.clear();
        this.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x666666, 50);
        this.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 100);
        for (var i:Number = 0; i < numPoints-1; i++)
        {
            mids[i] = {x:(points[i].x + points[i + 1].x) / 2, y:(points[i].y + points[i + 1].y) / 2};
        }
        mids[i] = {x:(points[i].x + points[0].x) / 2, y:(points[i].y + points[0].y) / 2};
        this.graphics.moveTo(mids[0].x, mids[0].y);
        for (var j:Number = 0; j < numPoints - 1; j++)
        {
            this.graphics.curveTo(points[j+1].x, points[j+1].y, mids[j+1].x, mids[j+1].y);
        }
        this.graphics.curveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y, mids[0].x, mids[0].y);
        this.graphics.endFill();

        var point:Object;
        for (var k:Number = 0; k < numPoints - 1; k++)
        {
            point = points[k];
            spring(point, points[k + 1]);
            mouseSpring(point);
        }
        spring(points[k], points[0]);
        mouseSpring(points[k]);

        for (var l:Number = 0; l < numPoints; l++)
        {
            point = points[l];
            point.vx *= damp;
            point.vy *= damp;
            point.vy += grav;
            point.x += point.vx;
            point.y += point.vy;

            if (point.y > stage.stageHeight)
            {
                point.y = stage.stageHeight;
                point.vy = 0;
            }
            if (point.x < 20)
            {
                point.x = 20;
                point.vx = 0;
            }
            else if (point.x > stage.stageWidth)
            {
                point.x = stage.stageWidth;
                point.vx = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private function spring(p0:Object, p1:Object):void
    {
        var dx:Number = p0.x - p1.x;
        var dy:Number = p0.y - p1.y;
        var angle:Number = p0.a+Math.sin(p0.wave += speed)*2;
        var tx:Number = p1.x + dist * Math.cos(angle);
        var ty:Number = p1.y + dist * Math.sin(angle);
        var ax:Number = (tx - p0.x) * k;
        var ay:Number = (ty - p0.y) * k;
        p0.vx += ax * .5;
        p0.vy += ay * .5;
        p1.vx -= ax * .5;
        p1.vy -= ay * .5;
    }

    private function mouseSpring(p:Object):void
    {
        var dx:Number = p.x - stage.mouseX;
        var dy:Number = p.y - stage.mouseY;
        var dist:Number = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        if (dist < 40)
        {
            var angle:Number = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
            var tx:Number = stage.mouseX + Math.cos(angle) * 40;
            var ty:Number = stage.mouseY + Math.sin(angle) * 40;
            p.vx += (tx - p.x) * k;
            p.vy += (ty - p.y) * k;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Graphics APIs use an evenOdd winding, which means if a filled path overlaps itself, it negates the fill.

You need to use the [Graphics.drawPath](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#drawPath%28%29) function with a winding value of "nonZero".  This will cause it not to negate when the path overlaps itself.  Check out this [little demo](http://www.flashandmath.com/basic/drawpathCS4/), make a shape that overlaps itself, and switch the winding from evenOdd to nonZero to see how it works.

As for translating your code, instead of using graphics.moveTo() and .curveTo() calls in your update() routine, you'll need to build up a description of your path (aka, the inputs to drawPath) and pass them into graphics.drawPath() last.  Adobe shows an example [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WSA8BD9022-BAB1-46d3-9B26-0D9649743C8E.html).